# Low-Res Facebook Photos after moving to new 8.1 phone

Tags: contacts

The user had a Lumia 920 running 8.1, where Facebook contact photos were high quality. They purchased a new Blu WinHD phone and successfully restored from the last backup.

The same Facebook contacts' profile photos are now ***very*** low-res. This is most noticeable when the contact makes a phone call to the user and the caller's Facebook photo is shown on the Incoming Call screen.

Has anyone experienced this (regardless of device)? If yes, what steps did you take to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same issue :(

Workaround: click on each contact and wait for it to sync. With 1k contacts, it'll take a while, lucky, most of them don't have a facebook account :)